# How to make this linq to sql tranaction success

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql, foreign-keys

how to add tranasction in this linq to sql code

```
MyDBDataContext DB = new MyDBDataContext();
            SurveyClient objMaster = new SurveyClient();
            objMaster.SurveyID = int.Parse(dtQuestions.Rows[0]["SurveyID"].ToString());
            MembershipUser myObject = Membership.GetUser();
            myObject.ProviderUserKey.ToString();
            objMaster.UserID = Guid.Parse(myObject.ProviderUserKey.ToString());  //Guid.Parse("993a109d-a0c7-4946-a8da-99fb594f3ce2");// current userID
            objMaster.SurveyDate = DateTime.Now;
            DB.SurveyClients.InsertOnSubmit(objMaster);
           // DB.SubmitChanges();

            foreach (DataRow dr in dtQuestions.Rows)
            {
                int currQueScore = GetAnswerScore(dr["AnswerType"].ToString().Trim(), dr["ClientAnswerValue"].ToString().Trim());
                dr["ClientAnswerScore"] = currQueScore;
                myScore += currQueScore;
                SurveyClientAnswer objDetail = new SurveyClientAnswer();
                objDetail.SurveyClientID = objMaster.SurveyClientID;
                objDetail.QuestionID = int.Parse(dr["QuestionID"].ToString());
                objDetail.Answer = dr["ClientAnswerValue"].ToString();
                objDetail.Score = int.Parse(dr["ClientAnswerScore"].ToString());
                DB.SurveyClientAnswers.InsertOnSubmit(objDetail);
               // DB.SubmitChanges();
            }
            objMaster.FinalScore = myScore;
            DB.SubmitChanges();
```

when i comment the two DB.SubmitChanges() 
it throws error

```
The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint "FK_SurveyClientAnswers_SurveyClientAnswers". The conflict occurred in database "NEXLEV", table "dbo.SurveyClient", column 'SurveyClientID'.
The statement has been terminated.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were on the right path, but thinking too much "database oriented".

Indeed the objMaster does not have an ID yet, and that is causing the problem. But in Linq you should not assign a master-ID to a detail instead  you assingn the master to the detail entity classes instead (or the other way around):

Sohe problem is this line:

```
objDetail.SurveyClientID = objMaster.SurveyClientID;
```

it should be changed to

```
objDetail.SurveyClient = objMaster;
```

In that case, there is no need for transaction management because it will all work in one SubmitChanges() and Linq will add the transaction for you and it is also smart enough to manage the setting of the ID's the correct way

[assumption: you have your foreign key constrains set up in the DB]

Comment: But could describe a little, how does it work? objDetail.SurveyClient = objMaster;

Answer (score 0):

You do not have assigned the objMaster.SurveyClientID because it is not in the database and does not have a Id when you assign it to your SurveyClientAnwser. The first (commented) DB.SubmitChanges() does send the changes to the database, and the objMaster.SurveyClientID will be assigned (auto assign in your db). Then the objDetail.SurveyClientID = objMaster.SurveyClientID; line does assign a real id to you SurveyClientAnwser.

To make one transaction you have to make a transaction scope:

```
  MyDBDataContext DB = new MyDBDataContext();
  using (TransactionScope ts = new TransactionScope())
  {
      SurveyClient objMaster = new SurveyClient();
      objMaster.SurveyID = int.Parse(dtQuestions.Rows[0]["SurveyID"].ToString());
      MembershipUser myObject = Membership.GetUser();
      myObject.ProviderUserKey.ToString();
      objMaster.UserID = Guid.Parse(myObject.ProviderUserKey.ToString());  //Guid.Parse("993a109d-a0c7-4946-a8da-99fb594f3ce2");// current userID                  
      objMaster.SurveyDate = DateTime.Now;                  DB.SurveyClients.InsertOnSubmit(objMaster);
      DB.SubmitChanges();
      foreach (DataRow dr in dtQuestions.Rows)                 
      {
            int currQueScore = GetAnswerScore(dr["AnswerType"].ToString().Trim(), dr["ClientAnswerValue"].ToString().Trim()); 
            dr["ClientAnswerScore"] = currQueScore;
            myScore += currQueScore;  
            SurveyClientAnswer objDetail = new SurveyClientAnswer();                      
            objDetail.SurveyClientID = objMaster.SurveyClientID;   
            objDetail.QuestionID = int.Parse(dr["QuestionID"].ToString()); 
            objDetail.Answer = dr["ClientAnswerValue"].ToString(); 
            objDetail.Score = int.Parse(dr["ClientAnswerScore"].ToString());       
            DB.SurveyClientAnswers.InsertOnSubmit(objDetail);
            // DB.SubmitChanges(); //no need for this one
      }
      objMaster.FinalScore = myScore;
      DB.SubmitChanges();      

      ts.Complete();
  }
```

Comment: i was doing the same as you see my commented code above, but to make it transaction safe i made it like this..

Comment: Sorry but this way you are not using Linq-2-sql at its full potential here. There is no need for doing the transaction yourself, no need for the extra submitchanges . Just assign the master entity to the detail instead of setting the ID and it all works.